# Div width:100% not working during initial form load in IE11,Works in other browser

Tags: html, internet-explorer, bootstrap-4

[![enter image description here][1]][1]Please help me how to sort this issue, my Div id header "Coverage " during initial form load it sets to width content,but after refresh it width is 100%. This issue not occurs in Chrome and Mozilla.

````
<div id="functDiv" style="width: 101%;height:22px;font-weight:bold;padding-left:2px;font-family: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:12px;background-color: gainsboro;">Coverage</div>
<table id="tblList" class="table table-hover" style="width: 100%;margin-bottom:0px;font-family: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:12px;">
<tbody>
<tr style="line-height: 0.1;border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;" id="trFnId"> 
<td readonly="" style="padding-left: 0px;">Marketing</td>
<td style="padding:2px;width: 6%;"><button type="button" id="btnID" class="col-sm-4 btn btn-warning fa fa-trash" style="font-weight:bold;margin-top: 2px;margin-right: 33px;margin-left: 21px;" name="btnDelete" aria-hidden="true" ></button></td></tr> </tbody></table>
;```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8lzq.gif
````

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to provide additional information.  Your div has an id of "functDiv" and content of "Coverage," not an id of "Coverage."  If that is the div that you are referring to, you have explicitly set its width to 101%.  I would expect it to take up the entire width of its enclosing container.
Shawn

Comment: I have explicitly declared div width:101%, still only during initial page load it shrinks to content width,but after page refresh its 101%width. Please help me

Comment: Please throw some light on this!

Answer (score 0):

I try to test the sample code that you had shared in the original post.

I noticed that Div id header "Coverage" has 101% width all the time in the IE 11 browser.

Test result:

[image]

I get the same result with the 100% width. It works normally.

I can see that you had written the inline CSS. It can be possible that some other CSS code on the page affecting the result on your side. You can directly try to run the above sample in the IE browser to see whether it works or not. If it works then you can try to check for any other CSS code on the page that may help to narrow down the issue.

If the issue persists then you can try to share some more code. We can try to make a test with it and we can try to provide further suggestions.

Comment: Thanks Deepak for the comments. I checked but unable to find what I miss. When i inspect element and uncheck the width:100% and check again it immediately displays full width:(

Comment: If possible for you then you can try to share some more code. We can try to check the code to find the cause of the issue.

Comment: Hi Deepak, Sure. I just figured out that this issue is replicated only in IE version 11.0.195 . IE 11.0.200 it looks fine. I will also share the code shortly

Comment: From your comment it looks like the issue with the specific IE browser update and issue can be fix by installing the latest Windows updates. I suggest you can post your solution as an answer and you try to mark your own answer to this question. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.